# How to create actual dataframes out of k-fold-stratified in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

Out of the indices which i get back from sklearn Stratifiednfold, how to create from every fold a corresponding dataframe?

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
skf.get_n_splits(X, y)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

prints out the lists with indices. How to map these back to my original Dataframe?

I need them because i want to add my augmented data to the trainingdata before i run my texclassification model on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your original dataframe with the list of indices you have as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
indices = [0, 2, 4]
df = df[df.index.isin(indices)]
```

Output:

```
  foo
0   a
2   c
4   e
```